# Using Excel VBA to input a value into Internet Explorer textbox

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

New to VBA/StackOverflow/etc. My code currently opens Internet Explorer, navigates to a URL, checks to see if it's logged in, logs in if necessary, then navigates to a new page.

Now I'd like to input a string value into an Internet Explorer textbox.

Here's the relevant elements' HTML source code:

```
<input type="text" class="search_customDate" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom"
value="mm/dd/yy" size="13" 
onchange="RTSDHTMLUTIL.getRTSDHTML('dateFrom').onChange(event);" 
OnFocus OnBlur />

<input type="text" class="search_customDate" name="dateTo" id="dateTo" 
value="mm/dd/yy" size="13" 
onchange="RTSDHTMLUTIL.getRTSDHTML('dateTo').onChange(event);" 
OnFocus OnBlur />    <INPUT id="dateTo" class="search_customDate" 

<input type="text" class="search_companyLookupField" name="tokens" id="tokens" 
value title OnChange OnMouseOver OnMouseOut OnKeyDown="doLookup(event);" 
OnKeyUp OnFocus OnBlur OnDisable />
```

Here's relevant portion of my code:

```
'Input From and To dates
Dim DateFrom As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Set DateFrom = AppIE.Document.getElementByID("dateFrom")
If Not DateFrom Is Nothing Then
    DateFrom(0).Value = "05/05/05"
End If

Dim DateTo As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Set DateTo = AppIE.Document.getElementByID("dateTo")
If Not DateTo Is Nothing Then
    DateTo(0).Value = "06/06/06"
End If

Dim Ticker As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Set Ticker = AppIE.Document.getElementByID("tokens")
If Not Ticker Is Nothing Then
   Ticker(0).Value = "XYZ"
End If
```

As of now, nothing appears in the text boxes and I can't seem to figure out why. Would love anyone's input/advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's where I would start:

- remove the "(0)" after your HTML element variables names - the getElementByID method returns unique elements, not collections
- make sure that the HTML input elements you are trying to retrieve aren't actually returning nothing